# XPath expression workaround for max predicate

Tags: xml, xpath

Given this XML:

```
<foos>
    <foo>
        <name>Apple</name>
        <rank>1</rank>
        <key>asdfasdfasdf</key>
    </foo>
    <foo>
        <name>Orange</name>
        <rank>3</rank>
        <key>qwerqwtwetqw</key>
    </foo>
    <foo>
        <name>Apple</name>
        <rank>2</rank>
        <key>zxcvzxvcxzb</key>
    </foo>
    ...
</foos>
```

I'm trying to find the key of the foo with a particular name, let's say "Apple", that has the highest rank. I'm using the following xpath expression (a workaround for the lack of a max function):

```
/foos/foo[name='Apple' and rank >= /foos/foo[name='Apple']/rank]/key/text()
```

However I'm sometimes getting multiple results back, even though every name-rank combination is unique. Where am I going wrong here?

This is being used in Java - if that turns out to be relevant I can post the entire code.

Comment: Hmm never tried, but it's going to return a nodeset, ie everything but the minimum rank, I should think. Come tho think of >= will return the minimum as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/foos/foo[name='Apple'][not(preceding-sibling::foo[name='Apple']/rank>./rank) and not(following-sibling::foo[name='Apple']/rank>./rank)]/key/text()
```

Comment: Could you please explain what this is doing and how it differs from my solution? Still learning the subtleties of xpath.

Comment: As you know, /foos/foo[name='Apple'] evaluates to a node set (node set A).  This is further filtered by the next [] expression, which is applied to each element in the set.  Anything in node set A to make it through the filter will comprise node set B.  The expression asks the following of each node ("me") in node set A:  "Are there any preceding siblings (i.e. any "foo" earlier than "me" in the XML) whose rank is bigger than my rank.  If so, filter me out.  Also, if there are any following siblings, count me out too.  Only nodes from A that make it to B will have no sibs with higher ranks.

Comment: Hmm, actually I was unable to get yours working. It seems to return no results in some cases. This can be reproduced with my example on http://www.xpathtester.com/ and http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm

Comment: I see my error:  In my pre-edit version if there is a sibling "foo" that is not an apple with a higher rank, no apple makes it to node set B.  The modified example should work.

Comment: Aha - I'm surprised I didn't catch that either since I had to use the same nested predicate in mine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out:

```
/foos/foo[name='Apple' and not(rank < /foos/foo[name='Apple']/rank)]/key/text()
```

This is necessary because the right side of the test is true for *any* values returned by `/foos/foo[name='Apple']/rank`, so the old version picked up any "Apple" foo with a rank greater or equal to any other "Apple" foo.